# Unity Engine set Active random Child Object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make an Apocalypse Game and have a Zombie Model with different Materials as Children, I want to randomly activate them, wehn the Zombie spawns (in void start)

I have tried different options, like this:

```
public class RandomSkin : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Zombie;

    void Start()
    {
        int randomChildIdx = Random.Range(0, Zombie.transform.childCount);
        Transform randomChild = Zombie.transform.GetChild(randomChildIdx);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now.

Comment: So .. what didn't work as expected in what you tried? So far you of course only get a `randomChild` and never do anything with it ... I would expect some `randomChild.gameObject.SetActive(true);` ..